# Not able to retrieve all cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I have the following which I am trying to use to retrieve data from a JSON response, my problem is how ever it only retrieves 2 out of the 3 cookies and all three are needed to process the response verification.

---

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    'email': 'someone@email.com',
    'password': 'password'
}

userAgent = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like MacOS X; en-us)'
                  'AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10'}
with session() as c:
    response = c.post('https://companion.orerve.net/user/login', headers=userAgent, data=payload)
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.cookies)
```

---

The header contains all the cookies but the cookieJar only is displaying 2

---

```
{'content-length': '565', 'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 
'set-cookie': '
CompanionApp=uvpkui0vdi47funvjehg64auo6; path=/, 
mtk=1429041176%7C%7C7edcb7bc2f93785ccbd6e5216c5a252679d4ae2d; domain=companion.orerve.net; path=/; expires=Tue, 14-Apr-2015 19:52:56 UTC; secure, 
mid=1444938776%7CbRo65nOCl0SCyrFojxnwiQ%3D%3D%7Cf33c5b778deea444a21706edc27d6e439f39f89c; domain=companion.orerve.net; path=/; expires=Thu, 15-Oct-2015 19:52:56 UTC; secure', 
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Apache', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-ua-compatible': 'IE=edge', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-transform', 'date': 'Wed, 15 Apr 2015 19:52:56 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}

<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie mid=1444938776%7CbRo65nOCl0SCyrFojxnwiQ%3D%3D%7Cf33c5b778deea444a21706edc27d6e439f39f89c for .companion.orerve.net/>, <Cookie CompanionApp=uvpkui0vdi47funvjehg64auo6 for companion.orerve.net/>]>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked this ~17 hours ago, and when you did the expiration date on the second cookie was almost certainly well-past due.

```
mtk=1429041176%7C%7C7edcb7bc2f93785ccbd6e5216c5a252679d4ae2d; domain=companion.orerve.net; path=/; expires=Tue, 14-Apr-2015 19:52:56 UTC; secure,
```

Specifically note

```
expires=Tue, 14-Apr-2015 19:52:56 UTC
```

17 hours ago, it was definitely still 15-Apr-2015 in UTC.

If a cookie has already expired, requests does not store it.

Comment: are you able to force storing the cookie?, also the website in the example and script is valid so if you run this you  will get the same results, I have just re-ran the script and the cookie value for expiration is still the 15th.

Comment: 98% of requests cookie-handling is done by the standard library's `cookielib` module. The `RequestsCookieJar` implements nice convenience methods on top of that. The policy of rejecting that cookie means that the stdlib is doing its job. I don't know of a way to force it into the cookiejar but there may be information on docs.python.org that describe how to do that (despite it being a terrible idea).

Comment: It's also possible the server is misconfigured. You should check your browser to see if it stores this cookie when you log into the site

Comment: You were 100% correct, after walking though how a browser handled the cookies it did not store the "mtk" cookie, it would appear that the initial mtk cookie is used as reference for the authenticated session, once the verification code was submitted it is re-issued with a correct expire date and is stored.